# WIF and WCF - Accessing Thread.CurrentPrincipal inside service method with AspNetCompatibilityMode turned off

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, wif, claims-based-identity

I have a web application with a silverlight app on one of the pages. The website is secured using WIF. I am attempting to make a WCF call from silverlight to a service hosted in the same appdomain as my website.

If I have AspNetCompatibilityMode enabled this works fine. The browser has already authenticated and so when the WCF call is made the FedAuth cookies are sent up by the silverlight client and WIF correctly sets the HttpContext.Current.User from the session cookies (FedAuth/FedAuth1).

Unfortunately I need to have AspNetCompatibilityMode turned off. In this case I can see that the silverlight WCF call still passes the FedAuth cookies to the server and the SessionAuthenticationModule correctly sets the Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Unfortunately, the sessionauthenticationmodule seems to run in a different thread from the actual WCF method I am trying to invoke therefore I have lose the identity somewhere along the WCF/WIF pipeline.

Is there a way around this? I have tried creating a custom implementation of SessionAuthenticationModule and overriding SetPrincipalFromSessionToken (inside which I can access my claims etc.) but I am not sure where I can store the principal so that I have acess to it after the channel handler dispatches the call to my service on another thread.